# Asking for Tag creation

Tags: extensions

I would like to use this community to give support for my Joomla! extensions.

http://extensions.schultschik.com

This for I would like to get a tag like "SchuWeb", "SchuWebExtensions" or something else.

Would this be ok for the community and could someone create a tag for me?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to JSE. I'm closing this as off-topic. Please ask your question on the [Joomla Meta site](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/) and it can be discussed.

Comment: Thx @Lodder didn't have the min requirement to post on meta, so will come back on this when I reached it.

Comment: I created a meta discussion: https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/support-for-schuwebextensions-on-jse @Lodder

Comment: I created a meta discussion: https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/support-for-schuwebextensions-on-jse @svanschu - Please share your vision and ideas in that discussion about how this may work.